# Как правильно передать переменные в javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть такой код, никак не дойдет как прописать переменные в javascript код. Посредством php, как у меня сейчас, вроде тоже работает, но нужно сделать по-правильному.

```js
    $("#switch<?=$rg?>-<?=$pg?>").on("click", function(){
        if (this.innerHTML=='<img src="img/ico/viem_p.png">') {this.innerHTML = '<img src="img/ico/viem_c.png">';
   });
   }
        else this.innerHTML = '<img src="img/ico/viem_p.png">';
        return false;
    });
```

```html
 echo '<a id="switch'.$rg.'-'.$pg.'" href="#"><img src="img/ico/viem_p.png"></a>';
```

Comment: Что вы понимаете под `но нужно сделать по-правильному`?

Comment: чтоб не было переменных php в скрипт коде

Comment: Их все равно где-то придется прописывать, в теле страницы например, чтобы передать значения переменных из `php` в переменные `javascript`.

Comment: @AlexProsto, а вы ведь знаете, что у вас JS код невалидный? ;)

Comment: я много чего не знаю, поэтому и вопросы возникают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью html-данных data как-то так:

```
<a id="switch" href="#" data-rg="<?=$rg?>" data-pg="<?=$pg?>">
  <img src="img/ico/viem_p.png">
</a>
```

В jQuery потом можно получить значения так:

```
var rg = $("#switch").data('rg');
var pg = $("#switch").data('pg');
```

Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: а как мне потом правильно засунуть в джава скрипт

Comment: Ну вон, написал же: `var rg = $("#switch").data('rg');` Вставляете это в ваш js-скрипт (его нужно вызвать строго после загрузки страницы) — после этого в переменной `rg` в скрипте у вас будет значение переменной `$rg` из php, которую вы использовали при генерации html-документа.

Comment: Что-то не работает

Comment: в принципе разобрался только вместо data использовал attr

Answer (score 2):

Если переменных много, то имеет смысл передавать их как массив PHP и преобразовывать в объект JS. А для данного варианта

```
var rg = '<?=$rg?>';
var pg = '<?=$pg?>';
    $("#switch"+rg+"-"+pg).on("click", function(){
            if (this.innerHTML=='<img src="img/ico/viem_p.png">') {this.innerHTML = '<img src="img/ico/viem_c.png">';
                });
                }
            else this.innerHTML = '<img src="img/ico/viem_p.png">';
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: это так вообще делается если javascript код внутри sql запроса, а что делать если я хочу javascript код отдельно прописать от запроса?

Answer (score 0):

В "скрипт коде" не бывает PHP переменных.
В чем можно легко убедиться, открыв исходный код сайта в браузере. Никаких переменных РНР там не будет. Переменные РНР бывают только в РНР коде. Ну так они там и должны быть.

Вопрос непонятен. В первом примере переменные РНР выводятся так, как нужно. Что мешает сделать так же во втором?

```
?>
    <a id="switch<?=$rg?>-<?=$pg?>" href="#"><img src="img/ico/viem_p.png"></a>
<?
```

Повторюсь. **В момент, когда исполняется JS код, никакого РНР в нем уже нету**, и продублироваться он не может. Рекомендую к прочтению [Самые основы. Как работает PHP.](http://phpfaq.ru/na_tanke)

Comment: получается, что при выводе 200 элементов он продублируется 200 раз, а это мне не надо